# Phonegap (Cordova 1.9.0 based) alerts are not working when the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method is enabled

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

Phonegap notifications (`navigator.notification.alert` and `navigator.notification.confirm`) are not working while using `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` for URL request processing.

Javascript:

```
function onBodyLoad() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
  navigator.notification.alert("Cordova is working");
}
```

Objective C:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"js-call:"]) {
      // Extract the selector name from the URL
      NSString *requestString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
      NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
      NSString *function = [components objectAtIndex:1];
      NSLog(@"the function name is  %@",function);
      // Call the given selector
      [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(function)];
      // Cancel the location change
      return NO;
    }
    return YES;
  }
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into very similar issue. Changing the last line

```
return YES;
```

to

```
return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
```

All commands to plugins go through gap:// bridge. **shouldStartLoadWithRequest** gets called for every such call. So, defaulting to **YES** appears to be the issue. When in fact, it should return **NO** for gap:// calls.